# Replacement and stringification of #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

I am trying to understand what is the flow of replacement of same2, same1 and concatenate in:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define concatenate(a,b) a##b
#define same1(a)  #a
#define same2(a)  same1(a)
main()
{
        printf("%s\n",same2(concatenate(1,2)));
        printf("%s\n",same1(concatenate(1,2)));
}
```

I have tried to understand this from many places but I am not able to get it. Can somebody please explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
#define concatenate(a,b) a##b
#define same1(a)  #a
#define same2(a)  same1(a)
```

when you have `same2(concatenate(1,2))`, the argument of `same2` is expanded before passing it to `same1`, so there, `concatenate(1,2)` is replaced by its result, `12` that then is stringified by `same1` to produce `"12"`.

With `same1`, no expansion of the macro argument occurs, since it's preceded by the stringification token `#`:

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified, argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below), is replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been expanded. Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.

(section 6.10.3.1 (1) in n1570)

Comment: `Before being substituted, each argument’s preprocessing tokens are completely macro replaced as if they formed the rest of the preprocessing file; no other preprocessing tokens are available.` Can you please explain this a bit?

Comment: The "as if they formed the rest..." means that macros defined later aren't in scope, only macros defined before, so if one of the tokens matches such a macro, it is not replaced. Is that what you wanted explained?

Comment: Daniel, I appreciate your effort but I am still in a doubt why same2(concatenate(1,2)) replaces concatenate(1,2) as 1##2 and then same2 as same1. But this does not happen so when I try the same thing with same1(concatenate(1,2)); means why is concatenate(1,2) not replaced by 1##2 first?

Comment: `same2(a)` is defined to become `same1 ( a )` (adding whitespace to separate tokens). Now the argument (`a`) is not preceded by either `#` or `##`, nor followed by `##`, so in an invocation of `same2`, the passed argument is macro-expanded. When the argument is `concatenate(1,2)`, the macro `concatenate` is invoked, with the arguments `1` and `2`, giving `1 ## 2`, then the `##` operator is applied (before the token sequence is rescanned for further macro replacements) producing the token `12`. That contains no more macro names, so that is passed to `same1`, so we're at `same1 ( 12 )`.

Comment: Now the result of the replacement of `same2`'s argument is rescanned for macro invocations (but `same2`, if it occurred as a token would not be substituted again). By the definition of `same1`, that results in `# 12`. Then the `#` operator is applied, producing `"12"`. In the replacement list of `same1`, the argument (`a`) is preceded by a `#` token, so the stringification operator is applied before the replacement list is rescanned for macro expansion, so the creation of the string happens before it is checked if the argument contains a macro invocation.

Comment: Thanx Daniel, I have understood it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your `concatinate(a,b)` becomes `concatinate(1,2)` when 1 and 2 are passed as parameters. That in turn becomes `1##2` which translates to `12` because `##` is a concatenating operator. So parameters 1 and 2 are concatenated to become 12

`Same1(a)` becomes simply `#a`, where `#` is stringisizing operator (See http://c-faq.com/ansi/stringize.html). So `Same1(12)` becomes `"12"` and when printed out to console

`Same2(a)` is the same as `Same1(a)`, which is simply `#a`, which just outputs parameter a as-is; so the output of `Same2(a)` where parameter a is 'Concatenate(1,2)' is just a string "Concatenate(1,2)"

Comment: You are saying it completely opposite. The output is:
12     
concatenate(1,2)

Comment: yes, the parameter to the first printf becomes #(a##b), where a is 1 and b is 2, so it becomes "12"; parameter to the second printf s simply #a which becomes "concatinate(1,2)"